# Change class on click not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to change the class of an item with jQuery, but I can't seem to make it work. For some reason, nothing at all is happening.

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#theSpinner").click(function() {
        $("#theSpinner").toggleClass("spinning");
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="reload">
    <img src="spinbut.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" id="theSpinner" class="notspinning">
</a>
```

I've tried with:

```
$("#theSpinner").click(function() {
    $("#theSpinner").removeClass("notspinning");
    $("#theSpinner").addClass("spinning");
});
```

aswell as `$("#reload")` instead of `$("#theSpinner")`, and with an `onClick=""` to a javascript function containing the addClass / removeClass part.

I really don't know what's the problem, but any way around this bull would make me very happy.

Comment: as an additional comment, you should use `this` instead of the same selector inside the click function...

Comment: @DarkAjax I was! It was in the original code, I was just getting desperate. Thanks though!

Comment: Your code is working fine. What do you expect to see?

Comment: @Gerard Apparently I needed to ensure it had been loaded, that's all (see answer below). =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your jQuery code within a "document-ready" block to ensure that jQuery has been loaded prior to calling your function :

```
<script>
    // Example of a document ready function
    $(function(){
        // When jQuery has loaded, wire up this function
        $("#theSpinner").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("spinning");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/niboxo/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants to toggle both `spinning` and `notspinning`.

Comment: Ah sheit. Worked like a charm. Can you elaborate why my jQuery wasn't loaded before? I mean, I just moved my code from one page to a template, basically.

Comment: @JohnSmith You were searching for the `#theSpinner` before it was on the page, finding nothing, and therefore not attaching the click listener to anything.

Comment: jQuery was being loaded, however your event handler is going to get called as soon as the page is loaded and jQuery might not be "ready" by that point. Wrapping it within that function will ensure that jQuery has been loaded and is "ready".

Comment: @Chris Not really, but it doesn't matter if they're both toggled, as only one class (spinning) contains some code. Only because my removeClass addClass didn't work.

Comment: If you did want to toggle between the two classes, you should be able to use `$(this).toggleClass('spinning notspinning');`

Comment: @RionWilliams toggles between "notspinning" and "spinning notspinning" this way which is fine too. Just waiting for the 15 mins to pass before I can mark the answer btw.

Comment: Right, I was just adding that that was an option as well if you wanted that behavior :)

Comment: @RionWilliams Well again, thank you very much. Always the stupid little things that gets me stuck for hours on end.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
<a href="#" id="reload"> <img src="spinbut.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" id="theSpinner" class="notspinning"> </a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#theSpinner").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("notspinning spinning");
  });
</script>
```